# ExceptionTranslationFilter redirecting to login page when using rememberMe

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, remember-me

In our project we where using spring-security 4.1.3 and the behavior was as follows :
when the user is a remember me and want to access a page that requires a full authentication, a redirection will be made to **a custom page (not login)  using AccessDeniedHandler** to enter a password confirmation from it

Once we upgraded to release 4.2.20 we are facing a problem with the remember me feature the application behaves as follow :
when the user is a remember me and want to access a page that requires a full authentication, a redirection will be made **to the login page**

When I checked the source code from spring-security I found that a change was made in the mentioned version

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/20577c39c1eba147a033624f37414f63aba2f99e/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/access/ExceptionTranslationFilter.java#L183

in the handleAccessDeniedException method a check of isRememberMe was added that it's causing the problem

I am wondering if this is the normal behavior for ExceptionTranslationFilter.java or I must added some customization in my code to make it works as before, if so how ? Thank you in advance.

This situation was mentioned in the original bug of spring-security https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/2427